# How to convert SQL entry into specific form in python given an input file of multiple SQL entries?

Tags: python, mysql

Let's say we have a text file containing a SQL entry on each line formatted as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(NUM, TIMESTAMP) VALUES ('0', '2016-04-26 15:38:07')
```

Is there a way to format this into the format below using a Python script?

```
[(26 Apr 2016 15:38:07)|0]
```

The number `NUM` can be multiple digits so this can't be done just using hard coded indices.

So, given a text file `input.txt`, how would you convert each line into the new format and save it as `output.txt`?

Comment: @gonz right now I just read each line and store it as a variable text.
I then just used hard brackets and hard coded the indices to build the output string. The difficulty is when the number is more than one digit

Answer (score 2):

What about regular expressions?

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
line = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(NUM, TIMESTAMP) VALUES ('0', '2016-04-26 15:38:07')"
m = re.search(r"VALUES \('(\d+)', '(.*)'\)", line)
num = m.group(1)  # => '0'
ts = m.group(2)  # => '2016-04-26 15:38:07'
date_str = datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%m %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
newline = '[({})|{}]'.format(date_str, num)  # => "[(2016-04-26 15:38:07')|0]"
```

More information or some code would help, the answer depends a lot in your data, the source, the format, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative to not using `re`.

```
import datetime
line = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(NUM, TIMESTAMP) VALUES ('0', '2016-04-26 15:38:07')"
num, date = line.split('(')[2].split(', ')
num = num.strip("'")
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')").strftime('%m %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
print('[({}), {}]'.format(date, num))
```

Comment: I'd go with re, but this will also do the trick, just want to point out that there's no need to revert the string twice like that, just use index the split result:  line.split('(')[2].split(', ') it's way easier to read (and more efficient) than line[::-1].split('(', 1)[0][::-1].split(', ')

Comment: @gonz youre absolutely right, by the way im all for your answer, i `timeit`ed against mine and `re` in actually faster. Its just you see so many `re` answers i wanted to show something different